# How to read an HDF5 compound datatype with unknown composition?

Tags: rust, hdf5, hdf

I have managed to read HDF5 data into rust using the [`hdf5` crate](https://docs.rs/hdf5/0.8.1/hdf5/) (shown below). But this method relies on knowing the exact structure of the dataset before hand.

In the data I am trying to read the column header names stay consistent but the order could vary and some could be present or not present. Currently all columns are `f64` so that simplifies the problem.

Ideally for the processing I am doing the data needs to end up in a vector of hashmaps `Vec<HashMap<String, f64>>` or inverted would also work `HashMap<String, Vec<f64>>`. Where the key is the column heading.

Even just reading in each line of the dataset as binary and me transforming it using the `descriptor` would work. I just can't seem to find a way of doing this using the library. Is there a way to do this without resorting to the C HDF Library?

```rust
    use hdf5::*;
    #[derive(H5Type, Clone, PartialEq, Debug)] // register with HDF5
    #[repr(C)]
    struct Wrap {
        time: f64,
        px: f64,
        py: f64,
        pz: f64,
        r: f64,
        u: f64,
    };

    let file = File::open("file_1.hdf")?;
    let ds = file.dataset("object")?;
    let data_type = ds.dtype()?;
    let descriptor = data_type.to_descriptor()?;

    let data: Vec<Wrap> = ds.read_raw()?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others have my same question I figured I would post what I ended up doing. I couldn't find a way to solely use the high level portion of the crate to do it, so I just used pieces of the Rust HDF crate and the external c function wrappers exposed by hdf5_sys (installed by the hdf5 crate).

The code to get a column of data should look something like this:

```rust
use hdf5::*;
use hdf5::types::*;
use hdf5::globals::*;
use hdf5_sys::{h5s, h5p, h5d, h5t};

let name_file = String::from("file_name.h5");
let name_ds = "dataset_name";
let name_col = "col_name";

let file = File::open(name_file).expect("Could not open given HDF file.");
let ds = file.dataset(name_ds).expect("Could not open dataset.");
let buffer = &mut [0.0_f64; 1000]; 
let name = to_cstring(name_col.as_ref()).unwrap();
let ds_id = self.ds.id();

unsafe{
    let dt_id = h5t::H5Tcreate(h5t::H5T_class_t::H5T_COMPOUND, 8);
    h5t::H5Tinsert(dt_id, name.as_ptr(), 0, *H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5d::H5Dread(ds_id, dt_id, h5s::H5S_ALL, h5s::H5S_ALL, h5p::H5P_DEFAULT, buffer.as_mut_ptr().cast());
}

let buffer_vec = buffer.to_vec();

pub fn to_cstring<S: Borrow<str>>(string: S) -> Result<CString> {
    let string = string.borrow();
    #[allow(clippy::map_err_ignore)]
    CString::new(string).map_err(|_| format!("null byte in string: {string:?}").into())
}
```

This obviously isn't production level code, but it should help anyone looking for a path forward.

Note. if you don't know the data type of the column either you can get the column descriptors using:

```rust
let data_type = ds.dtype().expect("Could not find datatype.");
let descriptor = data_type.to_descriptor().expect("Could not ascertain datatype descriptor.");
```